# How to inject @Service bean into test junit 5 via constructor, so application doesn't crash?

Tags: java, spring, junit, dependency-injection, spring-test

Suppose I have a business logic layer in my spring boot application. To simplify:

```
public interface SimpleClass {
    public String getString();
}

@Service
public class SimpleClassImpl implements SimpleClass {

    public String getString(){
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

I need to test a single method. I wrote something like this:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ComponentScan("there is path to my directory")
class SimpleClassImplTest {

    private SimpleClass simpleClass;

    @Autowired
    SimpleClassImplTest(SimpleClass simpleClass){
        this.simpleClass = simpleClass;
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetString(){
     assertNotNull( simpleClass.getString());
    }    
}
```

That is, in the test, I want to inject an instance of the business logic class through the constructor (this is necessary for my tasks). The application however crashes with error:  `org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: Failed to resolve parameter in constructor.`

**Question:** how to change (what to add) to SimpleClassImplTest so that the bean is normally injected through the constructor?

Comment: have you tried to direclty `@Autowired` the field? and remove the test constructor?

Comment: @EmanuelTrandafir We have command agreement, that we will inject via constructor.

Comment: @ZufarSunagatov yes, but I am not full satisfy

Answer (score 0):

> Question: how to change (what to add) to SimpleClassImplTest so that
> the bean is normally injected through the constructor?

1. Annotate constructor with `@Autowired`.
2. As you use Unit 5, use the `@ExtendWith` instead of the deprecated `@RunWith` annotation.

Here is the code:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ComponentScan("there is path to my directory")
public class SimpleClassImplTest {

    private final SimpleClass simpleClass;

    @Autowired
    public SimpleClassImplTest(SimpleClass simpleClass){
        this.simpleClass = simpleClass;
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetString(){
        assertNotNull(simpleClass.getString());
    }
}
```

If you want to test the `SimpleClass interface` without any concrete implementation, you can use a mock object framework like `Mockito` to create a mock object of the `interface`.
Here is the code:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class SimpleClassImplTest {

    @Mock
    private SimpleClass simpleClass;

    @Test
    public void testGetString(){
        when(simpleClass.getString()).thenReturn("Hello World");
        assertNotNull(simpleClass.getString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. It's work for me, but I prefer to code at  the interface level. 
In you code variant please type  @Autowired
    public SimpleClassImplTest(SimpleClassImpl simpleClass) as in your answer

Comment: @AndrewKachalin I fixed it, check

Comment: @AndrewKachalin all good?

Comment: Not all good. Your implementation doesn't work without @SpringBootTest(classes = SimpleClassImpl.class)

Comment: @AndrewKachalin all good, now? :-)